# NSArray filled with bool

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to create an NSArray of bool values. How many I do this please?

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] init];
array[0] = YES;
```

this does not work for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

NSArrays are not c-arrays. You cant access the values of an NSArray with `array[foo];`
But you can use c type arrays inside objective-C without problems.

The Objective-C approach would be:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
//or
[array addObject:@(NO)];
...
BOOL b = [[array objectAtIndex:0] boolValue];
....
[array release];
```

---

EDIT: New versions of clang, the now standard compiler for objective-c, understand [Object subscripting](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html). When you use a new version of clang you will be able to use `array[0] = @YES`

Comment: I'm trying that and its giving me *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSNumber numberWithBOOL:]: unrecognized selector sent to class

Comment: should be [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]. Sorry, my mistake

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you've confused c array with objc NSArray. NSArray is more like a [list](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html) in Java, into which you can add objects, but not values like NSInteger, BOOL, double etc. If you wish to store such values in an NSArray, you first need to create a mutable array:

```
NSMutableArray* array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

And then add proper object to it (in this case we'll use NSNumber to store your BOOL value):

```
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:yourBoolValue]];
```

And that's pretty much it! If you wish to access the bool value, just call:

```
BOOL yourBoolValue = [[array objectAtIndex:0] boolValue];
```

Cheers, 
Pawel

Answer (score 2):

Use `[NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]` to get an object you can put in the collection.

Comment: array[0] = [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]; gives me an 'incompatible types in assignment' error

Comment: [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]