# How to store a boolean value to an NSArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

So I'm storing user settings in a plist file and to do that I'm adding data to an NSArray. This approach is working for me.

My problem is that now I'm adding a UISwitch to the settings and I was wondering how to store their ON/OFF state to the array so that I can access that state at a later time?

I'm adding data to the array like this:

```
[array addObject: mySwitch.on];
```

Then I'm trying to set the state like this:

```
[mySwitch setOn:[array objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSArray filled with bool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889186/nsarray-filled-with-bool)

Comment: You use `NSNumber` to store a boolean value and retrieve it - kind of like how you wrap a gift in a box before sending it to your relative :) See my answer for how to use it with your `UISwitch`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Since `NSArray` only takes in `(id)`s (i.e. Objective-C pointers to objects), you can only store objects.

The common way to store a `BOOL` value in an object is with the `NSNumber` class:

```
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:mySwitch.on]];
```

To access it, grab that `NSNumber` object and send it a `boolValue` message:

```
[mySwitch setOn:[[array objectAtIndex:0] boolValue]];
```